# Build a list from events

Tags: list-manipulation, procedural-programming

Say I have a list of elements of type

```
{name, direction, time}
```

where `direction` can be `in` or `out` and represent the `time` the person `name` has entered or leaved a meeting. The list is sorted by the `time` of the event.

I would like to build a list of elements of type

```
{number-of-people, time-interval}
```

where `number-of-people` is `0` at the beginning and is incremented by `1` if someone enters or decremented if leaves. `time-interval` is the time between events.

I could build the list like this

```
list2 = {};
numberOfPeople = 0;
prevTime = list1[[1,3]];
Do[
  {name, direction, time} = list1[[i]];
  numberOfPeople += If[direction === in, 1, -1];
  AppendTo[list2, {numberOfPeople, time-prevTime}];
  prevTime = time,
  {i, 2, Length[list1]}
]
```

but I am pretty sure that there are far better and concise ways.

Comment: Lookup `MovingMap`. Something like `MovingMap[func, list1, 1]`, where `func` returns `{n, dt}`.

Comment: @MichaelE2: I tried but I don't seem to understand how to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1];
dates = Sort[RandomSample[With[{first = Now}, 
     DateRange[first, DatePlus[first, Quantity[1000, "Minutes"]], "Minutes"]], 20] ];

events = RandomChoice[{3, 1} -> {"in", "out"}, 20];

names = RandomWord["Noun", 20];

data = Transpose[{names, events, dates}];

Grid @ data
```

[image]

Prepend `dates` with an initial date and use [`Differences`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Differences.html)to get durations.

```
time0 = Now - Quantity[10, "Minutes"];
durations = Differences[Prepend[time0]@data[[All, 3]]];
```

Replace `"in"` with with `1` and `"out"` with -1 in the second column of `data` and use [`Accumulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html) to get `numberofpeople`:

```
numberofpeople = Accumulate[data[[All, 2]] /. {"in" -> 1, "out" -> -1}];
```

Add the new columns to `data`:

```
newdata = Join[data, List /@ numberofpeople, List /@ durations, 2];

Grid @ newdata
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I only need to know about `Accumulate` and `Differences`, there are so many functions that sometimes you don't find what you're looking for